# break if method takes more than 30sec time to execute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I benchmarked the execution time for method

```
tests.each do |test|
  time = Benchmark.realtime { method(test) }
end

def method(test)
   code
end
```

Which is returning time in seconds

But what I want is to break the loop if this method is taking more than 30 sec of execution time.

suggest a clean way to do it.

Comment: Use `Timeout`: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html

Comment: Thanks, It really helpful

Answer (score 3):

Use stdlib `Timeout`

```
require 'timeout'
def method(test)
  Timeout::timeout(30){
    #code here
  }
end
```

This will raise `Timeout::TimeoutError` if code takes longer to run

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Ruby Timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) method

```
require 'timeout'

tests.each do |test|
  Timeout::timeout(30) {
    method(test)
  }
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You already got several answers, especially some regarding `Timeout`.

Please be cautious here. `Timeout` is implemented with an ALARM signal in standard ruby (i.e., I'm not talking about JRuby here), which means

- You cannot nest timeouts (that is, you can, but it will silently fail).
- If your code or some gem also uses the ALARM signal, it will go wrong.
- Things can go plainly wrong (unexpected behaviour) due to it being such a clunky mechanism.
- Don't even try to mix it with the "green multithreading" of standard ruby unless you like to have major headaches.

If you can, it will always be safer to somehow do your timeout yourself. That is, if you can, then have your `method` check for time spent regularly. Of course, this may or may not be useful to you; you don't want to bring test stuff into your production code. And it may be hard if you want to timeout system calls (for example, blocking network calls).

At least, keep it in mind.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
tests.each do |test|
  time = Benchmark.realtime { method(test) }
  break if time > 30
end
```

Not sure about the unit of `time`. Adjust the condition `time > 30` according to that.

Comment: Too bad the OP did not specify if he wants to actually interrupt the method, or just break out of the loop after the fact. :/